# AlamoFire + SwiftyJSON on iOS 9.0

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, swifty-json, alamofireimage

I have been trying to install and use AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON on iOS 9 using CocoaPods.  The latest version keeps getting installed and it is not compatible with iOS 9.0.

My PodFile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Kitchology' do

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'AlamofireImage'

end
```

I tried commenting them out and doing a pod install to remove them, then put them back in and do another pod install.  Every time the latest is installed.

I do have the project itself set to iOS 9.0 and NOT iOS 9.3 for the project build on all versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out.  I deleted the pods by commenting them out and running `pod update`.  Then we deleted the workspace.  Then comes the main part of the solution - we deleted everything in the derived data folder.  You can find this location in Xcode->Preferences Locations.  Although a clean should delete this data, it obviously did not.

Now we recreate the pods again.  Do a `pod init`, add the pods back into the Podfile and do a `pod install`.  Open the workspace and everything was then good.

This was a problem with cached data in Xcode.

Comment: i have same problem...please visits this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647430/swiftyjson-error-with-xcode-7