# SwiftyJson error with Xcode 7

Tags: iphone, swifty-json

I am new to IOS development. I am trying to implement SwiftJson library with my Xcode 7.3.1 but it gives me lots of errors. I don't know why. In my mac book i have two Xcode ,Xcode 8 and Xcode 7.3.1. I went through this [link](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/661) but it didn't help me.

I have also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464748/alamofire-swiftyjson-on-ios-9-0?rq=1) SO question. But it also not working.

Currently i want to run my project with Xcode 7.3.1

Here is my Pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'AlamofireDemo' do
   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.2’
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

Please help me.

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 does not support Swift 3 so you need to checkout the Swift 2 branch https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/swift2

Comment: thnx a lot...let me try it